# Opening an external link in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I can't open an external link correctly in my ionic app.

I have an event model that contains a url `event.orglink`

I can load a link if I have the url string like so;

```
<a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com/', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
 Open link
</a>
```

but I can't open the link properly from my model...

```
<h4>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.open({{event.orglink}}, '_system', 'location=yes');"> {{event.orginfo}}</a>
</h4>
```

how can I use the `event.orglink` url in `window.open` ?

Comment: try href="{{event.orglink}}" or href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="window.open({{event.orglink}}, '_system', 'location=yes');"

Comment: @Nikhil href="{{event.orglink}}" opens the link twice, once from the href and once from onclick, the other suggestion doesn't work

Comment: oh i mean remove the onclick if you add the href

Comment: Dont add onclick if you are using href. @raphael_turtle

Comment: @Nikhil then how can I add  '_system', 'location=yes' to the url?!